# Finding Product-of-Maxterms Form

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need help to resolve this problem, i have the following boolean function:

```
[(A.!C)+!(A.!C)].!(A.!B)
```

The Truth table is:

[image]

(please see this [LINK TO wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28A%20AND%20%21C%29%20OR%20%21%28A%20AND%20%21C%29%29AND%21%28A%20AND%20%21B%29) for more detail)

Then the **Sum-of-Minterms Form** is:

```
A.B.C + A.B.!C + !A.B.C + !A.B.!C + !A.!B.C + !A.!B.!C
```

And the **Product-of-Maxterms Form** is:

```
(A + !B + C).(A + !B + !C)
```

¿Is this correct? ¿How do I demonstrate this? Because I tried to find the maxterms starting from the initial Boolean function, for example:

```
 [(A.!C)+!(A.!C)].!(A.!B)
= [(A.!C)+!(A.!C)].!(A.!B)
= (A.!C + !A + C).(!A + B)
= (!A + !C + C).(!A + B)
= (!A + 1).(!A + B)
= !A + B
= .....
= (A + !B + C).(A + !B + !C)  ???????????????
```

I do not understand how to find (A + !B + C).(A + !B + !C).

Please appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call your expression $f$,
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\and}{~And~}
\DeclareMathOperator{\or}{~Or~}
\DeclareMathOperator{\nt}{~Not~}
\DeclareMathOperator{\T}{{\color{blue}T}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\F}{{\color{red}F}}
f = \bigg((A \and \nt C) \or \nt (A \and \nt C)\bigg) \and \nt (A \and \nt B) $$

$$\begin{array} {c|ccc|c}
& A & B & C & f \\ \hline
\text{Row 1} & \T & \T & \T & \T \\
\text{Row 2} & \T & \T & \F & \T \\
\text{Row 3} & \T & \F & \T & \F \\
\text{Row 4} & \T & \F & \F & \F \\
\text{Row 5} & \F & \T & \T & \T \\
\text{Row 6} & \F & \T & \F & \T \\
\text{Row 7} & \F & \F & \T & \T \\
\text{Row 8} & \F & \F & \F & \T \\
\end{array}$$

Notice how your sum of minterms has 6 terms.  Your truth table also has 6 "true" entries.  To construct minterms, you just list the "true" cases:

$$\begin{align}f &= 
(\text{Row 1}) \or 
(\text{Row 2}) \or 
(\text{Row 5}) \or 
(\text{Row 6}) \or 
(\text{Row 7}) \or 
(\text{Row 8})\\
&= ABC \or AB\overline C \or \overline ABC \or \overline AB\overline C \or \overline A\overline BC \or \overline A\overline B\overline C\end{align}$$

To construct the product of maxterms, look at the value of $\nt f$.  There are 2 cases when $f$ is false:

$$\begin{align}\nt f &= (\text{Row 3}) \or (\text{Row 4}) \\
&= A\overline B C \or A \overline B \overline C\end{align}$$

Now apply DeMorgan's:
$$\begin{align}
\nt\nt f &= \nt(A\overline B C \or A \overline B \overline C) \\
       f &= (\overline A\or B\or \overline C) \and (\overline A \or B \or C)
\end{align}$$

Your given answer for "product of maxterms" is the value of $f(\nt A, \nt B, \nt C)$.  Perhaps you are working with a different definition.

Comment: Wow! great answer, thanks, but i do not understand something,
so the correct form of product of maxterms is:
`(!A OR B OR !C) AND (!A OR B OR C)`
but this is not equal to
`A!BC OR !(ABC)`.

Comment: Please see this [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxNgay9IsYFfSUFSbVdNMVhMMVk/edit), I construct the minterms from initial function using boolean rules (Truth table unused)

Comment: Let's call the answer you got $g$, so $g = (A + !B + C).(A + !B + !C)$.  Check the value of $f$ and $g$ when $A = \text{true}, B = \text{false}, C = \text{false}$.  You will see that they are different.  $$~$$ As far as deriving the minterms algebraically, first find a sum-of-products.  Then for each term $x$ that is missing a variable $y$ apply the rule $x = xy + x\overline y$.  For example, you have derived $!A + B$.  Since $!A$ is missing $C$, apply $!A = !AC + !A!C$.  Keep doing that until all terms have all variables.